# exif_imagetype() [function.exif-imagetype]: Filename cannot be empty

Tags: php

I have a website where i have given my users an option to upload their picture and i have set a condition like if they didnt select any file for uploading and if they click the upload button without choosing a picture they get an alert box, but apart from that my website is showing the error that i am pasting below.

> Warning: exif_imagetype() [function.exif-imagetype]: Filename cannot be empty in      /mounted-storage/home98a/sub009/sc61374-HGPS/sitakalyanam.com/newsita/php4upload.class.php        on line 86

well line 86 piece of code i am attaching..

```
    function _doSafeUpload ()
{
    preg_match('/\.([a-zA-Z]+?)$/', $this->_params['name'], $matches);
    if (exif_imagetype($this->_params['tmp_name']) &&       in_array(strtolower($matches[1]), $this->_types))
    {
        if ($this->_params['size'] > $this->_maxsize)
            $this->_errors[] = $this->_lang['E_SIZE'];
        else
            $this->_im_status = true;

        if ($this->_im_status == true)
        {
            $ext = substr($this->_params['name'], -4);
            $this->new_name = md5(time()).$ext;

            move_uploaded_file($this->_params['tmp_name'], $this-        >_upload_dir.$this->new_name);

        $this->imgurl =$this->new_name;

        //$this->imgurl = .$this->new_name;


        }
    }
    else
        $this->_errors[] = $this->_lang['E_TYPE'];
}
```

i dont want to show the error getting displayed in my webpage for my user. instead      i want to show them or intimate them that they have not selected any file for uploading.

here i am uploading the complete code.but no errors if uploading files are selected     error comes only if no file is choosen for uploading

```
    <?php
   /*

  - PHP4 Image upload script

  */

   class imageupload
  {
  //pblic variables
    var $path = '';
    var $errorStr = '';
    var $imgurl = '';

    //private variables
    var $_errors = array();
    var $_params = array();
    var $_lang = array();
    var $_maxsize = 1048576;

    var $_im_status = false;

    //public methods
    function imageupload ()
 {
    //require 'photouploadconfig.php';

    if($_GET['Choice']=="1")
    {           
   require 'Photouploddir1.php';
   }
   elseif ($_GET['Choice']=="2")
   {
   require 'Photouploddir2.php';
   }
   elseif ($_GET['Choice']=="3") 
   {
   require 'Photouploddir3.php';
   }
   elseif ($_GET['horoschoice']=="1")
  {
  require 'horosuploaddir.php';
  }
  elseif ($_GET['videoChoice']=="5")
  {
  require 'videouploaddir.php';
  }


        $this->_types = $types;
        $this->_lang = $lang;
    $this->_upload_dir = $upload_dir;
    $this->_maxsize = $maxsize;

        $this->path = $PHP_SELF;

        if (is_array($_FILES['__upload']))
        {
            $this->_params = $_FILES['__upload'];
            if (function_exists('exif_imagetype'))
                $this->_doSafeUpload();
        else
                $this->_doUpload();

            if (count($this->_errors) > 0)
                $this->_errorMsg();
        }
     }

    function allowTypes ()
    {
        $str = '';
        if (count($this->_types) > 0) {
            $str = 'Allowed types: (';
            $str .= implode(', ', $this->_types);
            $str .= ')';
        }

        return $str;
    }  

       // private methods
    function _doSafeUpload ()
    {
        preg_match('/\.([a-zA-Z]+?)$/', $this->_params['name'], $matches);
        if (exif_imagetype($this->_params['tmp_name']) == exif_imagetype($this-           >_params['']))
        { 
          print '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
              print 'alert("Opps! You Have Not Choosen Any Photos For Uploading.Kindly          Select Choose File Tab For Uploading.")'; 
               print '</script>'; 
               print "<script>";
               print " self.location='photoupload.php';";
               print "no photo uploaded";
                  print "</script>";
        }  
        if (exif_imagetype($this->_params['tmp_name']) && in_   a      rray(strtolower($matches[1]), $this->_types))
        {
            if ($this->_params['size'] > $this->_maxsize)
            $this->_errors[] = $this->_lang['E_SIZE'];
        else
            $this->_im_status = true;

        if ($this->_im_status == true)
        {
            $ext = substr($this->_params['name'], -4);
            $this->new_name = md5(time()).$ext;

                move_uploaded_file($this->_params['tmp_name'], $this->_u        pload_dir.$this->new_name);

            $this->imgurl =$this->new_name;

        //$this->imgurl = .$this->new_name;


        }
            }
       else
        $this->_errors[] = $this->_lang['E_TYPE'];
                } 

        function _doUpload ()
       {
    preg_match('/\.([a-zA-Z]+?)$/', $this->_params['name'], $matches);
    if(in_array(strtolower($matches[1]), $this->_types))
    {
            if ($this->_params['size'] > $this->_maxsize)
            $this->_errors[] = $this->_lang['E_SIZE'];
        else
            $this->_im_status = true;

        if ($this->_im_status == true)
        {
            $ext = substr($this->_params['name'], -3);
                $this->new_name = md5(time()).$ext;

                move_uploaded_file($this->_params['tmp_name'], $this->_u          pload_dir.$this->new_name);

                $this->imgurl = ''.$this->new_name;

    //$this->imgurl = ''.$this->_upload_dir.''.$this->new_name;
    //$this->imgurl = ''.$this->new_name;

                //$this->imgurl = $this->_upload_dir.'/'.$this->new_name;



            }
        }
    else
        $this->_errors[] = $this->_lang['E_TYPE'];
        }   

           function _errorMsg()
           { 
         $this->errorStr = implode('<br />', $this->_errors);
           }
           }

           ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This: `$this->_params['tmp_name']` does not apparently contain a file path. Normally you would get this data from `$_FILES['name']['tmp_name']` But you have some sort of abstraction which makes it difficult to see where the problem might be.

Comment: hi i have pasted the complete code. if the user choses any file no error is poping up but i the user by mistake if they dont choose any file for uploading then the warning error is displayed in the webpage screen at the user end....